# WPF applying theme

Tags: wpf

i have a WPF project using VS2010 that i'ld like to add a theme to it
What i've done is :

1. downloaded the WPFToolkit.msi, and ran it.
2. downloaded the Aero.NormalColor.xaml (for example) and added it to the project.

As references i added :

1. WPFToolkit
2. PresentationFramewoek.Aero

In the App.xaml i added this :
 ResourceDictionary Source="Aero.NormalColor.xaml"

The project run with no errors but still the theme not applied.
So can anybody tell me what i've been missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Try this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero,                        
        Version=4.0.0.0,                     
        Culture=neutral,                        
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,                        
        ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
```

Comment: i've already used that code and it didn't work.However, now am using other theme and it worked fine.i think there was something wrong with the references.
Thanks anyway for help !